# Setting Hidden Field Value to JSON (jQuery/JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, encoding

```
var c = [{"Id":40,"Action":null,"Card":"0484"}];
$('#hidJson', window.parent.document).val(c);
alert($('#hidJson', window.parent.document).val()); // returns [object Object]
alert($('#hidJson', window.parent.document).val()['Card'); // returns undefined
```

I'm in a legacy app. I have had to put in a fix where an IFrame needs to get a packet of JSON back to a parent.document. Then the data will be available server-side after I submit the parent doc.

Using alert to try to figure out what is happening. Do I need to encode the JSON first ( before I set it on the 2nd line of the JS.

**UPDATE**:
I see what it is doing now. It is setting the value in the DOM like so.

```
<input id="hidJson" name="hidJson" type="hidden" value="[object Object]" />
```

Comment: Works in other browsers too but here is some IE documentation on JSON.stringify http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc836459(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes.  otherwise you'll set the hidden to the result of ``c.toString()`.  firefox has`.toSource()` but that's not portable.  see http://www.json.org/ for an implementation.